# Webpart not appearing in site

Tags: web-part, powershell, deployment

We have deployed webpart using powershell but cannot find it under the Edit page-> add webpart -> custom, there is no folder called 'custom'. This folder otherwise comes up when deployed via VS.

```
$solution="mywebpart.wsp"
$path= $solutionPath + $solution 
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath $path
install-spsolution -Identity $solution -WebApplication $oURL  -GACDeployment
WaitForJobToFinish
```

We checked under central admin -> system settings -> manage farm solution, it shows that it is deployed to the correct URL.

Comment: Has the feature been activated?

Comment: oh. right. I will check this

Comment: Do I have to run powershell to activate the feature every time I create a new site collection? Is there anyway to automate this?

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature will also need to be activated in order for web part to show up. The next time you deploy a WSP, the feature will remain activated/deactivated depending on its state. That is, if the feature is activated and you deploy the WSP again, you won't need to activate the feature. However, if it is deactivated, it need to be activated again.

Comment: What about the other site collections present? And what about the site collections which will be created in future? Does this feature need to be manually activated so that they can use the webpart?

Comment: It will need to be activated in the new site collections.

Comment: is it possible to use feature stapling to achieve auto activation

Comment: Of course feature stapling can be used.